# Managing a user in visual studio online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to understand which settings are the ones associated with the source code. I don't want my team meber accidently going in an modifying/deleting source. He/she can manage the project (work items) but I don't want them messing with the source code. Is this the correct area under the security tab where those settings get modified?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would be better going into "CODE" tab online and selecting the root element (`$/MyTeamProject`) of your Team Project and select "Security...":

[image]

From there you can manage the source control permissions for users / groups.

If you want a group of people to have no source control access, stick them all in the same group and set that group to "**Deny**" for "Read". If you read-only, then **Deny** all except "Read".